# Enabled FIPS on a luks encrypted CentOS system - boot password not longer recognized

Tags: centos, luks

I have a CentOS VM instance which was software encrypted during install.  The system booted fine (after entering the boot decryption password).

My project requires enabling FIPS for OpenSSL, so I went through the [steps](https://niranjanmr.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/rhel6-fips/) and rebooted.

Now the system will not accept my boot decryption password (which is purposely easy to type).

On an otherwise identical system without software encryption, enabling FIPS using the steps above works fine, no problems rebooting.

**Edit**

I spun up a third CentOS VM instance, this time not using whole system encryption.  Next, I encrypted a volume using luks, then rebooted.  I'm prompted for the password and the system then boots normally.

Next, I enabled fips for openssl, rebooted - and get a plethora of errors where I'd usually see the boot password, and the system does not boot.

I booted this system into single user mode, pulled fips=1 from the kernel line and booted. The boot password was accepted this time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I encrypted the volumes before enabling FIPS.   As [garethTheRed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29406/gareththered) alluded to in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226661/enabling-fips-on-a-luks-encrypted-centos-system-breaks-boot-password?noredirect=1#comment385369_226661), LUKS used a non FIPS approved algorithm, so when FIPS was enabled things went bonkers.

The solution is to

1. Enable FIPS
2. Encrypt volumes

In that order.

[This guide](http://geekswing.com/geek/how-to-encrypt-a-filesystem-on-redhat-6-4centos-6-4-linux-fips-or-no-fips/) was also useful in solving the problem.  It is lengthy with extra explanation so I won't copy paste the full thing here.  Here's the jist:

**A. ENABLE FIPS**

1. Check if FIPS is enabled using one of two methods:

   ```
   cat /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
   0 = not enabled
   1 = enabled

   openssl md5 /any/file
   valid hash = not enabled
   "Error setting digest md5" = enabled (likely)
   ```
2. Check if you have prelinking turned on.

   ```
   vi /etc/sysconfig/prelink

   Change
   PRELINKING=yes
   to
   PRELINKING=no
   ```
3. Undo all current prelinking

   ```
   [root@centos64]# prelink -ua
   ```
4. Install `dracut-fips`

   ```
   [root@centos64]# yum install dracut-fips
   ```
5. Rebuild your initramfs

   ```
   [root@centos64]# dracut -f
   ```
6. Find device path of `/boot`

   ```
   [root@centos64]# df /boot
   Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
   /dev/sda2         487652 115447    346605  25% /boot
   ```
7. `cp /etc/grub.conf /etc/grub.bak`
8. Edit `/etc/grub.conf`

   ```
   Add in the "fips=1" and "boot=/dev/***" lines to the kernel command line 

   Example: 
   kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_centos6464bittempl-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_centos6464bittempl/lv_swap rd_LVM_LV=vg_centos6464bittempl/lv_root rd_NO_MD crashkernel=auto SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet fips=1 boot=/dev/sda2
   ```
9. Reboot
10. Check if FIPS is enabled (See Step 1 above).

**B. ENCRYPT VOLUME**

1. *Are you sure FIPS is enabled?  If not, do not proceed - go back to **ENABLE FIPS** and make sure that part is working before continuing...*
2. Get the device path of the logical volume you wish to encrypt.  In my example, this is `/dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03`
3. BACK UP ALL DATA ON THIS VOLUME.  It will be DESTROYED.
4. `umount` volume.

   In my case, `umount /db_fips`
5. `shred -v -n1 /dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03`
6. Encrypt volume and set passphrase

   ```
   cryptsetup -v --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03
   ```

   **NOTE**: a RHEL minimal install may not include cryptsetup by default.  Just `yum install cryptsetup` to get what you need.  CentOS 6.7's minimal package set includes `cryptsetup`.
7. Open the device and alias it to “somename” of your choice  (in this case, "db_fips")

   ```
   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03 db_fips
   ```
8. Verify mapper has the path

   ```
   [root@centos64]# ls /dev/mapper/db_fips

   At this point, treat /dev/mapper/db_fips as you would any ordinary filesystem or device
   ```
9. Create filesystem as you normally would

   ```
   [root@centos64]# mkfs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/db_fips
   ```
10. Mount it and verify it

    ```
    [root@centos64]# mount /dev/mapper/db_fips /db_fips
    [root@centos64]# date >> /db_fips/today.txt
    ```
11. **¡¡¡IMPORTANT!!!**: Comment out the existing `/etc/fstab` entry for the target volume, lest you have headaches on reboot. `:-)`

    `vi /etc/fstab`

    `# /dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03 /some/path ext4 defaults 1,2`
12. Reboot to ensure the steps above are working.
13. get `UUID` of encrypted volume

    `blkid`

    `/dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03: UUID="2e52ffee-7a02-4c91-b6bf-223b05f90ded" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"`
14. Add encrypted volume to `/etc/crypttab` - so it can be decrypted on boot.  You can specify a passfile here, but it is not recommended.  *Install DRAC in the server if it is to be remotely administered (so you can enter the pass phrase during boot).*  [crypttab man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crypttab)

    ```
    [root@centos64]# vi /etc/crypttab

    db_fips UUID="2e52ffee-7a02-4c91-b6bf-223b05f90ded"
    ```
15. Reboot to test.